# Sharing DLLs of .NET application in Linux

Tags: .net, linux, shared-libraries

I'm trying to run multiple .NET 5.0 processes using Ubuntu 20.04 and Docker. I noticed that every container opens ~130 file descriptors. Most of them are standard DLLs. I thought that they should be loaded once, in common .NET layer, and then only mapped to specific processes.

I tried again but without Docker. And it seems that the same thing happens. Every .NET process
ties to load DLL files on its own.

I cannot find any information about the behaviour of .NET DLL files in linux. Do they act as ordinary file and because of that they aren't shared between processes?

Comment: How are you measuring whether dlls are loaded once or not? Are you looking purely at the number of open file descriptors?

Comment: I'm looking in the listing from lsof and every .net process has two entries for each dll. One with FD 'mem' and one with file descriptor id. When I look for example on 'libstdc++.so' it only has one 'mem' entry.

Comment: Apart from that, when I run ~400 processes, my system file descriptor limit is exceeded.